# List values change if I change the array passed to Arrays.asList(array)

Tags: java, arrays

I have seen the code Arrays.class, but not able to understand why the changes made to the array is reflecting to ArrayList even though below code returns new ArrayList.

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Sample code:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = Arrays.asList(array);
        System.out.println("List created from array:  " + list);
        array[0] = 100;
        System.out.println("List after changing array:" + list);
    }
}
```

Output:

List created from array:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

List after changing array:[100, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: As per JavaDoc: Returns a fixed-size list *backed by the specified array*. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

Comment: Note that the `ArrayList` in question is a [`java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList) (a private nested class of `Arrays`), not a `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The list is backed by array as specified in document about [Arrays.asList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.)

And if you digging the line `return new ArrayList<>(a)` you will see:

```
private final E[] a; // This is internal array of List

ArrayList(E[] array) {
    a = Objects.requireNonNull(array);
}

public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    return obj; // Just return the array reference. No deep copy
}
```

So as you can see, the list does not copy the array data, just assign it reference to its internal array.

Hence your change to original array is reflected to the list and vice versa

Note that: `Arrays.asList()` return an instance of `Arrays.ArrayList<>`:

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable {
}
```

Unlike `java.util.ArrayList`, the `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` does not implement all of List functions. If you try to use methods like `add()`, it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: If i make changes to the list then array also get reflected??

Comment: Yes. `Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.`

Comment: But I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException while trying to add element to list.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks

Comment: The `add()` in the last paragraph is implicitly already covered by the first paragraph: "Returns a fixed-size list". Trying to add something to a fixed-size list is supposed to fail, of course.

Comment: Is there a library function to get a list from array which doesn't change if array changes.